# How does this recursive overload of the insertion operator (operator<<) work?

Tags: c++, recursion, operator-overloading

I'm in the process of learning about recursion. The below is a recursive overload of the insertion operator for a class which provides a linked list of integers. It compiles and runs, but I'm confused as to why.

When overloading the insertion operator, I understand that you normally return an `ostream` reference so that calls can be chained. However, wouldn't this function evaluate to something along the lines of `out << node`, then to `out << out << node`, and then to `out << out << out << node`, etc? Upon reaching the base case and beginning to return, it seems that you would be trying to insert an `ostream` into an `ostream`, which should cause an error, should it not?

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const IntList &intList) { 
   if (intList.head != nullptr) out << intList.head;
   return out;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, IntNode *node) { 
   if (node->next == nullptr) {
      out << node->value;
      return out;
   }
   else { 
      out << node->value << ' ';
      node = node->next;
      return out << node;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems that you would be trying to insert an ostream into an ostream

Nope. Your `<<` operator returns an `ostream`, but it does not mean that you're inserting it into another ostream.

every step you take in the recursive function, you insert something in the ostream and return the same ostream. See:

```
out << node->value;
...
out << node->value << ' ';
```

you always insert some value into the ostream.

this `return out << node;` means thet you will insert node->value into the ostream, and go to the next node (if there is a next node).

For better understanding, here the iterative method, it should work exactly as your recursive one:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const IntList &intList) { 
    IntNode *node = intList.head;
    
    while(node->next != nullptr){
        out << node->value << ' ';
        node = node->next;
    }
    out << node->value;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. I was thinking of `return out << node;` as a statement with two functions - one recursive (<< node) and one not (out) - so after the final node returned out, the next function on the stack would resolve to `out << out` etc. Really, it's equivalent to `return operator<<(out, node);`, so when out is returned by the final node, it will cause all of the previous function calls to return out, and returning &out from the recursive overload of the insertion operator function will allow for chaining insertion operators in the "outer" insertion operator

Comment: In your iterative example, the statement in the while loop would resolve from `out << node->value << '  ';` to `out << '  ';` and finally to a reference to `out;`, which would be discarded before the next iteration?

Comment: I fixed the iterative method as I noticed there was an error. it sould go through the entire list inserting each node's value and the white space. finally, insert the last node's value, and return the ostream

Comment: obviously, you must check this first: intList.head != nullptr